# Finding potential stack overflow issues in templates

Tags: c++, templates, stack-overflow

I traced a recent crash in my application to a stack overflow problem, and having fixed the problem, I thought I'd do a re-check on the code for any similar potential bugs using the visual studio code analysis tool.  This found a number of possible similar cases with a report such as

> Warning   C6262   Function uses '148140' bytes of stack:  exceeds
>   /analyze:stacksize '16384'.  Consider moving some data to
>   heap. SCCW-VC2015 c:\cpp\aclcommon\aclcontainer.h

When I look at the code it takes me to the following template function;

```
template<class TYPE, class ARG_TYPE, class INDEX>
inline INDEX CContainerBase<TYPE, ARG_TYPE, INDEX>::Add(ARG_TYPE newElement)
{ 
    TYPE Temp = newElement; 
    INDEX nIndex = GetSize();
    SetSize(nIndex  + 1);
    SetAt(nIndex,Temp);
    return nIndex; 
}
```

where the offending line is `TYPE Temp = newElement;`  The problem is that I need to find out which piece of code is using the templated container with such large elements, as the template itself is not the problem.  Is there anyway to find out which specific instantiation of the template is in use here, i.e. find out what `TYPE` refers to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach is to use [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) on the size of the element inside the template code, like this:

```
static_assert(sizeof(TYPE) < 16384, "Object is too large for the stack");
TYPE Temp = newElement;
```

This would break a compile in every place where the template is instantiated with a type that is too large for the stack.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight, just what I was looking for.

Comment: Just to add a note to the above for MSVC users, you need to look at the text output window to get the details needed, as the data in the error list is abbreviated and does not contain the specific value for TYPE.

Answer (score 1):

`typeid(TYPE).name()` provides a string suitable for debugging, typically the type's name according to the ABI name-mangling rules.